# Derive the equation for compound interest

Tags: binomial-theorem

I was trying to derive the equation for not continuous compound interest. I started as follows:
$$ P+P* \frac{R}{100x} = P[1+ \frac{R}{100x} ]$$ So $$ A = P[1+ \frac{R}{100x} ] + P[1+ \frac{R}{100x} ]* \frac{R}{100x} +P[1+ \frac{R}{100x} ]* [\frac{R}{100x}]^2+P[1+ \frac{R}{100x}]*[\frac{R}{100x}]^3+P[1+ \frac{R}{100x}]* [\frac{R}{100x}]^4+…+P[1+ \frac{R}{100x}]* [\frac{R}{100x}]^{x-1} $$
$$=P+2\frac{PR}{100x}+2[\frac{PR}{100x} ]^2+2[\frac{PR}{100x} ]^3+[\frac{PR}{100x}]^4+…+[\frac{PR}{100x} ]^x$$
Please note that the second $[\frac{PR}{100x}]^4$ is inside the $…$. I was not sure of if I should have still included it because it would appear with distribution of a term that was inside the $…$

Continuing the simplification

$$ A = P(1+2[\frac{R}{100x}]+2 [\frac{R}{100x}] ^2+2 [\frac{R}{100x}] ^3+ [\frac{R}{100x}]^4 +…+[\frac{R}{100x}]^x)$$

---

$$=P(\frac{R^x+…+R^4(100x)^{x-4}+2R^3(100x)^{x-3}+2R^2(100x)^{x-2}+2R(100x)^{x-1}+(100x)^x}{(100x)^x})$$

I do not understand how to simplify this further, however, as to get the normal equation the numerator would have to simplify to $(R+100x)^x$, but then how is it possible for all the coefficients to be 2 for the in between terms (the end terms have coefficient 1 as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go step-by-step.
$$P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)+ P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right) \frac{R}{100x}= P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right) \left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)= P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^2.$$

##### After this, the interest will be on $\displaystyle P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^2$ and not on $\displaystyle P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right) \frac{R}{100x}$.

So $$P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^2+ P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^2 \frac{R}{100x}= P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^2 \left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)= P\left(1+\frac{R}{100x}\right)^3.$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: I saw this while searching on my own as well, but does that mean that the way I am trying doesn’t work. If so, why not, or did I make some error?

Comment: I saw this while searching on my own as well, but does that mean that the way I am trying doesn’t work. If so, why not, or did I make some error?

Comment: Yes. By writing $P(1+\frac{R}{100x})(\frac{R}{100x}) ^2$ you’re assuming that the interest is on $P(1+\frac{R}{100x})(\frac{R}{100x})$.